# Is there some API on BlackBerry for "smooth" image resizing?

Tags: blackberry, bitmap, thumbnails, scaling

To get image thumbnails on BlackBerry I use EncodedImage.scaleImage32(). It works Ok, but when I open native image viewer (from the Camera app) I see the difference in quality - native viewer thumbnails look nice (smooth, anti-aliased), while mine are a bit ugly. Looks like native viewer resizes images using some filter (bicubic or smth like that). How can I do the same? Is there some API for "smooth" resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in 5.0, the Bitmap class has a method called scaleInto() which can use a filter to perform smooth scaling of an image.  The quality is MUCH better than scaling without a filter.  See [Bitmap.scaleInto()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html) for more information.